# rails server がうまくいかず困っています。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`rails server`しても立ち上がらなくなり昨日から大苦戦しております。どなたかこちらをご教授頂けませんでしょうか？

昨日ターミナルのBASHを色がついてるZSHに変えてターミナルにコマンドを打ちました。しばらくしてPHPとRuby on Railsをポート3000とポート8000で同時に立ち上げようとしました。

その際今まで `php artisan serv` や `rails server` で立ち上げていた制作物のページにエラーが走り見れなくなりました。ご教授いただきガリガリコマンドを打ちましたが直せませんでした。

railsやruby homebrewなど再インストールしてrailsのバージョンも2.4.1にしたのですがなぜか2.5.1を読みに行っているみたいです。

エラーはターミナルで `rails s` を打つと

```
MacBookPro:pictgram yokoyamanaonori$ rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    2: from /Users/yokoyamanaonori/pictgram/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/yokoyamanaonori/pictgram/bin/spring:10:in `read'
/Users/yokoyamanaonori/pictgram/bin/spring:10:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/yokoyamanaonori/pictgram/Gemfile.lock (Errno::ENOENT)
```

と表示されます。もしどなたかこちらのページを見ていただけましたら是非ご教授いただけますと
幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: シェルにはPATHの設定などが含まれているはずですから、まずは元のbashに戻して状況を確認するべきじゃないでしょうか。 / 合わせて、「YouTubeをみて真似してコマンドを」や「ガリガリコマンドを」で**具体的に**何をしたのかが分からないと、この質問を見た人に伝わらないと思います。

Comment: `bundle` は使用していますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gemfile.lockファイルが作成されてないため`bundle install`で作成してください。
また、bundle execからrailsを実行すると2.4.1を見に行くようになると思います。

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec rails server
```